# vector within vector generates duplicate values in second dimension

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

In the example below (which can also be seen in [Ideone](https://ideone.com/l1RXAE)), I have a `vector` of a class and inside the class I have an element also `vector`.

The problem is that when doing the `push_back` of the class, the internal vector `vetint` should start from the beginning again, for each push_back of the first dimension, but c++ is holding the previous values, hence the vector doubles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class classe
{
public:
    int var;
    vector<int> vetint;
};


int main()
{
    vector<classe> vetor;
    classe obj;

    for (unsigned i=0; i<2 ; i++) {
        obj.var = (i+1)*10;
        for (unsigned c=0; c<3 ; c++) {
            obj.vetint.push_back((c+1)*100);
        }
        vetor.push_back(obj);
    }
    for (unsigned i=0; i < vetor.size() ; i++) {
        cout << "var(" << i << ") = " << vetor[i].var << endl;
        for (unsigned c=0; c < vetor[i].vetint.size() ; c++) {
            cout << "vetint(" << c << ") = " << vetor[i].vetint[c] << endl;;
        }
    }
}
```

It produces this result:

```
var(0) = 10
vetint(0) = 100
vetint(1) = 200
vetint(2) = 300
var(1) = 20
vetint(0) = 100
vetint(1) = 200
vetint(2) = 300
vetint(3) = 100
vetint(4) = 200
vetint(5) = 300
```

When the desired one would be:

```
var(0) = 10
vetint(0) = 100
vetint(1) = 200
vetint(2) = 300
var(1) = 20
vetint(0) = 100
vetint(1) = 200
vetint(2) = 300
```

Why does it happen? How to solve?

Comment: do `obj.vetint.clear();` inside the `i` loop. Or move `classe obj;` to be inside the `i` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you unroll the first `for` loop, your code will be:

```
classe obj;

obj.var = (0+1)*10;
for (unsigned c=0; c<3 ; c++) {
   obj.vetint.push_back((c+1)*100);
}

// obj has three elements in it.
vetor.push_back(obj);

obj.var = (1+1)*10;
for (unsigned c=0; c<3 ; c++) {
   obj.vetint.push_back((c+1)*100);
}

// obj has six elements in it.
vetor.push_back(obj);
```

That explains whey the `vetint` of the second object in `vetor` has six elements.

You can fix the problem using one of the following methods:

#### Solution 1

Moving the declaration/definition of `obj` inside the `for` loop.

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<2 ; i++) {
    classe obj;
    obj.var = (i+1)*10;
    for (unsigned c=0; c<3 ; c++) {
        obj.vetint.push_back((c+1)*100);
    }
    vetor.push_back(obj);
}
```

#### Solution 2

Clear the contents of `obj.vetint` in the loop before adding items to it.

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<2 ; i++) {
    obj.vetint.clear();
    obj.var = (i+1)*10;
    for (unsigned c=0; c<3 ; c++) {
        obj.vetint.push_back((c+1)*100);
    }
    vetor.push_back(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that nothing makes `obj.vetint` empty after your first `push_back`s.   Tighten `obj`'s scope to the loop.

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<2 ; i++) {
    classe obj;
    obj.var = (i+1)*10;
    for (unsigned c=0; c<3 ; c++) {
        obj.vetint.push_back((c+1)*100);
    }
    vetor.push_back(obj);
}
```

You could also explicitly erase the contents of `obj.vetint` (`obj.vetint.clear()`), so take your pick.  Tightening scope is generally preferred, but there'd be a slight performance boost in this scenario if you clear (you'll avoid reallocating memory each loop iteration).

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop inside another for loop you are inserting integer values in to a vector.

First time it will insert {100, 200, 300} then  c becomes equal to 3 . it exits the inner for loop. i becomes 2 and then comes to inner for loop. c becomes 0 . again you are inserting values in to the same vector. So the vector values will become { 100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 300} .
You have to clear the vector list by calling vectorname.clear() before incrementing i value.